# How do I bind or resolve a Map that is spread amongst multiple PropertySource in a custom EnvironmentRepository for Spring Cloud Config server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I wrote a custom Spring Cloud Config EnvironmentRepository for Spring Cloud Config Server. I had to given the internal requirements of this product. It loads a variety of files from the file system that are not in YAML or property file format, among other things.

One of my goals was to make each file a PropertySource that would yield unique keys to a map.  However, it seems that only the first file based Property Source gets mapped in my configuration even though my config server exposes more.

Example, let's say a GET to cloud config:

http://localhost:8888/myproduct/default/master

yields the following response:

```
{
  "name" : "myproduct",
  "profiles" : [ "default" ],
  "label" : "master",
  "version" : null,
  "state" : null,
  "propertySources" : [ {
    "name" : "database:application-default",
    "source" : {
      "spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties" : false
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "database: myproduct-default",
    "source" : {
      "datasource.hostname" : "from@db.default",
      "product.name" : "myproduct"
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "cartridge-configs-1503",
    "source" : {
      "cartridge-configs[1503].cartridge.cartridgeId" : 1503,
      "cartridge-configs[1503].cartridge.cartridgeName" : "One",
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "cartridge-configs-1603",
    "source" : {
      "cartridge-configs[1603].cartridge.cartridgeId" : 1603,
      "cartridge-configs[1603].cartridge.cartridgeName" : "Two"    
     }
  }
  } ]
}
```

And on the client, I have the following configuration property

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyProductConfiguration {

   private Map<String, CartridgeConfig> cartridgeConfigs = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   public Map<String, CartridgeConfig> getCartridgeConfigs() {
      return cartridgeConfigs;
   }

   public static class CartridgeConfig {
      private long cartridgeId;
      private String cartridgeName;

      public setCartridgeId(long cartridgeId) {
         this.cartridgeId = cartridgeId;
      }

      public long getCartridgeId() {
         return cartridgeId;
      }

      public void setCartridgeName(String cartridgeName) {
         this.cartridgeName = cartridgeName;
      }

      public String getCartridgeName() {
         return cartridgeName;
      }
   }
}
```

It works, but only "cartridge-configs[1503]" loads.  Why?

What is the proper resolution for this, or workaround?

I am guessing that the only work around is to consolidate all the different property sources that share the same key for the map "cartridge-configs" into one property source as opposed to multiple ones.